Is there a theorem proving fixed-point iteration convergence in the complex plane?
Let's say you have a complex function $f$ defined on a open subset of the complex plane, such that it is holomorphic on a fixed point $τ$, and that $0<|f'(τ)|<1$.
And suppose there is a neighborhood $V$ of $f$ containing $τ$, such that $f(V)\subset V$. $f$ is holomorphic on $V$.
Is there a theorem saying that in this conditions, $\forall z \in V, f(f(f(f(...z))))=τ$?

Do you know Banach's fixed point theorem?

I heard it, I think it indeed is a solution for my question, but I'm unsure. I never learned it, nor what a metric space is, etc. Idk if it applies here, if it does, then question settled.

It is indeed a solution, you can find a neighbourhood of $\tau$ such that $|f'(z)|<1$ and then apply it.
